# Inserting an object inside an array fails

Tags: javascript

I have this data i have pulled from mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : "RLvWTcsrbRXJeTqdB",
    "examschoolid" : "5FF2JRddZdtTHuwkx",
    "examsubjects" : [
        {
            "subject" : "Z4eLrwGwqG4pw4HKX"
        },
        {
            "subject" : "fFcWby8ArpboizcT9"
        }
    ],
    "examay" : "NrsP4srFGfkc5cJkz",
    "examterm" : "5A5dNTgAkdRr5j53j",
    "examclass" : "gYF2wE4wBCRy9a3ZC",
    "examname" : "First",
    "examdate" : ISODate("2016-05-07T22:41:00Z"),
    "examresultsstatus" : "notreleased"
}
```

I want to iterate `examsubjects` and finally insert an object inside my array and get an array like this

```
"examsubjects" : [
{
"Z4eLrwGwqG4pw4HKX" : "0",
"fFcWby8ArpboizcT9" : "0"
}
],
```

This is my code

```
 var result = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < doc.examsubjects.length; i++) {
        var arr = {};
        for (var prop in doc.examsubjects[i]) {
            arr[doc.examsubjects[i][prop]] = 0;

        }
        result.push(arr);
    }
```

which gives me this array

```
"examsubjects" : [
        {
            "Z4eLrwGwqG4pw4HKX" : 0
        },
        {
            "fFcWby8ArpboizcT9" : 0
        }
    ],
```

How can i get the array i want?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your attempt, you initialize an empty array and push a new object into it for every object in your `examsubjects` array, when what you want to do is put the data from all your exam subjects into just one object, when you then apparently want to be in an array. One of the many ways to accomplish that is like this:

```
var result = [{}];
for (i = 0; i < doc.examsubjects.length; i++) {
    for (var prop in doc.examsubjects[i]) {
        // Here we repeatedly modify the single
        // object in our results array
        result[0][doc.examsubjects[i][prop]] = 0;
    }
}
// result now looks like [{"Z4eLrwGwqG4pw4HKX": "0", "fFcWby8ArpboizcT9": 0"}]
```

Comment: Please *explain* what you changed and why. What was the issue?

Comment: Result seems to have two elements, according to what i insert to mongo  https://jsfiddle.net/5kujy84o/

Comment: It was wrong placement of code,i got it to work. Thanks @Hamms and Kling, i shall remember you along my path of javascript learning.