# Inserting an object in array MongoDB FastAPI

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, fastapi

To begin, I have checked all these links, but none of them helped.

*[Insert an element into an array of nested model Mongodb with PyMongo on FASTAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72456687/insert-an-element-into-an-array-of-nested-model-mongodb-with-pymongo-on-fastapi)*

*[Inserting an object inside an array fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150817/inserting-an-object-inside-an-array-fails)*

*[how to insert an object to array in mongodb database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577716/how-to-insert-an-object-to-array-in-mongodb-database)*

*[MongoDB - Update or Insert object in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427610/mongodb-update-or-insert-object-in-array)*

So I have the document schema that looks like this:

[image: Documnent Schema]

*Postings* is an array of *Posting* objects, which have this schema:

[image: Posting Schema]

*_id* and *timestamp* are automatically generated, so the body of the request looks like this

```
{
    "title" : "new posting",
    "totalNumOfRoommates" : 17
}
```

My issue is that i cannot insert a new Posting Object, this is what I have tried thus far:

```
@router.post('/', response_description='Creates a posting for a specified user', response_model=postingModel.Posting)
async def addPost(post: postingModel.Posting = Body(...), userId: str = ""):
    user = await dbConnection.find_one({"_id" : userId})
    if user is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="User ID was not provided or was wrong, please provide it as a query parameter Example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/postings?userId=abcd-1234-efgh-5678",
        )
    
    post = jsonable_encoder(post)
    update_result = await dbConnection.update_one({"_id": id}, {"$push" : {"postings" : post} })
```

*post* looks exactly how I expect it to be, which is:

```
{
   '_id': '6de685e7-d55f-4412-99e1-adf03f013cdd', 
   'timestamp': '2022-10-19T16:44:23.190900', 
   'title': 'new posting', 
   'totalNumOfRoommates': 17
}
```

My question is, how can I insert an object into an array of objects using Python/FastAPI

Edit:
The stack trace is included below

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\httptools_impl.py", line 404, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 270, in __call__    
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 124, in __call__  
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 75, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 64, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in 
__call__
    raise e
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in 
__call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 680, in __call__       
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 275, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 65, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 231, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 160, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "D:\Bilkent Uni\Courses\CS 491\BilMate\Backend\.\postings\PostingEndpoints.py", line 26, in addPost
    update_result = await dbConnection.update_one({"_id": id}, {"$push" : {"postings" : post} }, upsert=True)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 52, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1019, in update_one   
    self._update_retryable(
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 868, in _update_retryable
    return self.__database.client._retryable_write(
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1498, in _retryable_write
    return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, None)
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1384, in _retry_with_session
    return self._retry_internal(retryable, func, session, bulk)
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1416, in _retry_internal
    return func(session, sock_info, retryable)
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 860, in _update       
    return self._update(
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 829, in _update       
    result = sock_info.command(
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 699, in command
    self._raise_connection_failure(error)
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 683, in command
    return command(self, dbname, spec, slave_ok,
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 120, in command
    request_id, msg, size, max_doc_size = message._op_msg(
  File "d:\bilkent uni\courses\cs 491\bilmate\backend\virenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\message.py", line 714, in _op_msg
    return _op_msg_uncompressed(
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: <built-in function id>, of type: <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

Comment: " i cannot insert " - why not?

Comment: what i meant to say is, when inserting, it does not work

Comment: Yes, this part is clear, you don't get the expected result. What I asked is to clarify what you get instead. Any errors?

Comment: @AlexBlex My bad, i misunderstood, I added the stacktrace if that helps

Comment: I'll let @AlexBlex write up the answer if they want, but the relevant portion of the error is `cannot encode object: <built-in function id>`.  When you retrieve the data you are doing so with `.find_one({"_id" : userId})`. But when you go to write it you have `.update_one({"_id": id},`.  I think that last `id` should be `userId`.

Comment: Cheers @user20042973 for picking it up. Just to confirm we don't intend to answer as it's clearly a typo and the answer won't bring much to the community.